# Sending an array to the R function (C++)

Tags: c++, r

I have written this function in c++:

```
extern "C"
{

    void add(int* first, int* second, int *n , int* sum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< *n; i++)
        {
            sum[i] = first[i] + second[i];
        }


    }
}
```

and this driver:

```
add <- function(twoColumn)
{
    if(!is.data.frame(twoColumn))stop("twoColumn should be data.frame")

    first <- twoColumn[1]
    second <- twoColumn[2]
    n <- length(first)
    .C("add",first = as.integer(unlist(first)),second = as.integer(unlist(second)),  n = as.integer(n),sum = as.integer(rep(0,n)))$sum


}
```

But the R out put is just a number for the sum of the first row of data frame.

Comment: Maybe n <- nrow(first) helps?

Comment: What is `length(first)`? Also, try `twoColumn[[1]]` etc and omit the unlist, no need for `as.integer(n)`, since `n` is already an integer, `sum=integer(n)` is more efficient than `rep...`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the problem is, but can provide a (somewhat over ambitious) working version of the code. It requires you to package the function, and works like this:

`src/add.cpp`:

```
SEXP add(SEXP Rx, SEXP Ry){
    SEXP xy_sum;
    int i;
    PROTECT(xy_sum = allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
    for(i = 0; i < length(Rx); i++){
        REAL(xy_sum)[i] = REAL(Rx)[i] + REAL(Ry)[i];
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return xy_sum;
}
```

`scr/add.h`:

```
#ifndef _add_ADD_H
#define _add_ADD_H

#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

extern "C" SEXP add(SEXP Rx, SEXP Ry);

#endif
```

`R/add.R`:

```
add <- function(x, y){
    if(length(x) != length(y)) stop("Vectors must be of the same length.")
    # coerce into numeric in case the user supplied something silly
    .Call("add", PACKAGE="add", as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y))
}
```

`R/zzz.R`:

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg){
    library.dynam("add", pkg, lib)
}
```

Comment: Nice. You can also use the inline package and cfunction() / cxxfunction() to do this on the fly without a package. And then there is Rcpp...

Comment: Thanks, this code has worked:
add <- function(twoColumn)
  {
    if(!is.data.frame(twoColumn))stop("twoColumn should be data.frame")
    
    first <- twoColumn[[1]]
    second <- twoColumn[[2]]
    n <- length(first)
    .C("add",first = as.integer(first),second = as.integer(second),
       n = as.integer(n),sum = as.integer(rep(0,n)))$sum
     

  }

Comment: The `inline` package does indeed simplify small things like this a lot. I just had a ready example on disc I'd written for other ppl before and thought I'd share it.